# Erro ao enviar a mensagem

Tags: php, envio-de-email

Estou com um formulário (que estava disponível no servidor) para envio de mensagens, sendo que ao fazer um teste para ver se o mesmo funcionaria, está me retornando um erro na seguinte linha:  `if(mail($to, $assunto, $mensagem, $headers))`.

Alguém poderia me ajudar nessa solução? Vou dispor todo código para melhor compreensão.

```
<?php

/* Valores recebidos do formulário  */
$arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo'];
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$replyto = $_POST['replyto']; // Email que será respondido
$mensagem_form = $_POST['mensagem'];
$assunto = $_POST['assunto'];

/* Destinatário e remetente - EDITAR SOMENTE ESTE BLOCO DO CÓDIGO */
$to = "mail@dominio.com.br";
$remetente = "mail@dominio.com.br"; // Deve ser um email válido do domínio

/* Cabeçalho da mensagem  */
$boundary = "XYZ-" . date("dmYis") . "-ZYX";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers.= "From: $remetente\n";
$headers.= "Reply-To: $replyto\n";
$headers.= "Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n";  
$headers.= "$boundary\n"; 

/* Layout da mensagem  */
$corpo_mensagem = " 
<br>Curriculo via site
<br>--------------------------------------------<br>
<br><strong>Nome:</strong> $nome
<br><strong>Email:</strong> $replyto
<br><strong>Assunto:</strong> $assunto
<br><strong>Mensagem:</strong> $mensagem_form
<br><br>--------------------------------------------
";

/* Função que codifica o anexo para poder ser enviado na mensagem  */
if(file_exists($arquivo["tmp_name"]) and !empty($arquivo)){

    $fp = fopen($_FILES["arquivo"]["tmp_name"],"rb"); // Abri o arquivo enviado.
 $anexo = fread($fp,filesize($_FILES["arquivo"]["tmp_name"])); // Le o arquivo aberto na linha anterior
 $anexo = base64_encode($anexo); // Codifica os dados com MIME para o e-mail 
 fclose($fp); // Fecha o arquivo aberto anteriormente
    $anexo = chunk_split($anexo); // Divide a variável do arquivo em pequenos pedaços para poder enviar
    $mensagem = "--$boundary\n"; // Nas linhas abaixo possuem os parâmetros de formatação e codificação, juntamente com a inclusão do arquivo anexado no corpo da mensagem
    $mensagem.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bits\n"; 
    $mensagem.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\n\n";
    $mensagem.= "$corpo_mensagem\n"; 
    $mensagem.= "--$boundary\n"; 
    $mensagem.= "Content-Type: ".$arquivo["type"]."\n";  
    $mensagem.= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$arquivo["name"]."\"\n";  
    $mensagem.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n";  
    $mensagem.= "$anexo\n";  
    $mensagem.= "--$boundary--\r\n"; 
}
 else // Caso não tenha anexo
 {
 $mensagem = "--$boundary\n"; 
 $mensagem.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bits\n"; 
 $mensagem.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\n\n";
 $mensagem.= "$corpo_mensagem\n";
}

/* Função que envia a mensagem  */
if(mail($to, $assunto, $mensagem, $headers))
{
 echo "<br><br><center><b><font color='green'>Mensagem enviada com sucesso!";
} 
 else
 {
 echo "<br><br><center><b><font color='red'>Ocorreu um erro ao enviar a mensagem!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Qual a mensagem do erro?

Comment: Seu erro está no if, use o comando: if(isset(mail($to, $assunto, $mensagem, $headers)))

Comment: Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 501 5.1.7 Bad sender address syntax 221 2.7.0 Error: I can break rules, too. Goodbye. in D:\web\localuser\dominio\www\envia.php on line 61.  Ocorreu um erro ao enviar a mensagem!  

No caso essa linha 61 é quase no final do arquivo:
if(mail($to, $assunto, $mensagem, $headers))

Comment: Tente subsituir o seu if da forma que eu falei, acredito que seja isso

Comment: @NicolasPereira fiz a alteração mas infelizmente não funcionou.  Ele retornou o seguinte erro ainda nessa linha:
Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in D:\web\localuser\dominio\www\envia.php on line 61

Comment: certo, vou dar uma revisada e ver o que pode ser

Comment: Qual é a linha 61 do seu código?

Comment: "SMTP server response: 501 5.1.7 **Bad sender address**"

Comment: A linha 61 é essa abaixo @NicolasPereira:
if(mail($to, $assunto, $mensagem, $headers))

Answer (score -3):

Isso funcionou para mim!

Se você achar que está recebendo erros 5.1.x ao tentar enviar
e-mails SMTP, pode ser que seu servidor de e-mail tenha o parâmetro
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes ou adere estritamente aos
protocolos ESMTP (RFC 5321) que exigem que os endereços de e-mail sejam incluídos <> como
Tente:
$to = "< mail@dominio.com.br >";
$remetente = "< mail@dominio.com.br >"; //Sem espaço entre os sinais